vscode devcontainers with docker-outside-docker. Starting a new docker container from inside the devcontainer mounts the file as a directory
Hi I have a setup where I'm using a devcontainer with the following structure:

My devcontainer.json if it helps:
{
    "name": "flowable-poc",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces",
    "forwardPorts": [8090],
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": {},
    }
}

My Devcontainers docker-compose file looks like this:
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  maven-repo:

services:
  app:
    container_name: flowable-poc-javadev
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspaces:cached
      - ../settings.xml:/home/vscode/.m2/settings.xml:ro
      - ${LINEVIEW_FLOWABLE_LICENSE_PATH}:/home/vscode/.flowable/flowable.license
      - maven-repo:/home/vscode/.m2

    user: vscode
    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

Once inside the container if you try to run another docker container and mount a file into it, it becomes a directory..
for example if I run this command from inside the devcontainer in the folder .devcontainer/licence:
docker run -it --rm -v flowable.license:/root/.flowable/flowable.license ubuntu bash -c "ls -la /root/.flowable"

the file becomes a directory:
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 26 11:53 flowable.license

Any ideas what I'm not understanding.
Do I need to use the host paths instead? that would be annoying as my java application is able to reference devcontainer files and folders etc
Thanks for any help

You can't directly mount a directory from one container into another; see for example Docker mount an directory of container to another container.  A docker run -v /host/path:... option always refers to the system where the Docker daemon itself is running, not the filesystem context where you're running the docker command.

Thanks I think that answers it...but what is the best way to handle this scenario? I think it would be quite common to work with docker inside a dev-container. I was Thinking maybe I need to define environment variables in my devcontainer json which reference the host paths... and use them around the project?
